# Communicating with bluetooth on Android without pairing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have come across this paper: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1507/1507.00650.pdf, and I am trying to implement a bluetooth based message sending mechanism without needing to pair over insecure rfcomm. Here is my implementation:

```
package me.twodee.protec;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.w("Protec", "It's here it's working here!");
            TextView out = findViewById(R.id.outlbl);
            out.setText("Here");
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Parcelable[] uuids = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
                for (Parcelable ep : uuids) {
                    String uuid = ep.toString();
                    Log.w("Protec", uuid);
                    Toast.makeText(context, uuid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.uuid = "ff724081-fe5d-4fb2-8745-af149cc2c0de";
    }

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String uuid;

    protected void setupStuff()
    {
        String regex = "([a-f0-9]{8})-([a-f0-9]{4})-4([a-f0-9]{3})-8([a-f0-9]{3})-([a-f0-9]{8})c0de";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(uuid.toLowerCase());
        if (m.find()) {
            String hexData = m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3) + m.group(4) + m.group(5);
            String binaryData = new BigInteger(hexData, 16).toString(2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void sendBluetoothMessage(View view) throws IOException
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("ff724081-fe5d-4fb2-8745-af149cc2c0de");
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    BluetoothServerSocket btSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("example",
                                                                                                                  uuid);
                    btSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.run();


    }


    public void rcvBluetoothMessage(View view)
    {
        IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything at all and I am unable to produce any output. I am fairly new to Bluetooth devices and Android, so if someone could point me towards the right direction and tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be of great help.

Two phones are intended to run the same app and one will send the message and the other will receive.

Here's my Android Manifest: https://gist.github.com/2DSharp/56cc43a20802accdcbd85314da4d7e73#file-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: Do you know what BroadcastReceivers, Activities and the Android lifecycle are?

Comment: I know what Activities and a slight idea about how the Android life cycle works. BroadcastReceivers, not so much. @SanilKhurana

Comment: Where do you call send... or receive... methods or the setupstuff method? Which btw. doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: @Ridcully I am sorry, I am not able to figure out when or how to call them. I need help to fill in the gaps because I am clueless as to how to move forward. The paper I attached assumes knowledge in Bluetooth management in Android, but I don't have much. So if you could give me a rough idea as to how to move forward I may be able to provide a better description of the problem.

Comment: You need to get a better idea of Android. I'd recommend start at the android developer doc

Comment: @SanilKhurana I understand, however is there something you could point me towards in the context of this post? That would be incredibly helpful :)

Comment: I could link BroadcastReceiver on android docs but to understand that you still need some knowledge of how Android works. At least a little bit. My advice to you is read about Activity, android lifecycle and receivers and how they work. Unfortunately you cannot read one topic you want to work with because it builds on the knowledge of other topics. There are a huge amount of resources about this and I would suggest spend at least 6-8 hours going through the relevant parts in the doc and making simple examples before you attempt this problem

Comment: @DEDIPYAMANDAS There is only one gap, but that is about 99% of the size of the whole application. So filling in this gap would basically mean to write your application for you.Do yourself a a favor and study the basics of Android first. It's not that hard and will not take too much time. Then you will be able to fill the gaps yourself.